# using range function excel with variables

Tags: excel, vba, variables, range

I would like to use variables within the range function, to assign adaptive range selection in excel VBA.

```
Range("A"&aa+4":C5"&bb+4).Select
```

where aa and bb are variables.

Thanks !

Comment: maybe this one: `Range("A" & aa+4 & ":C" & bb+4).Select`?

Comment: youre missing an additional `&` after the first `4` to have a proper concatenation. And please try to avoid using `.Select` you will find many resources on this with a quick search

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using this:

```
Range("A" + Strings.Trim(Str(aa + 4)) + ":C" + Strings.Trim(Str(bb + 4))).Select
```

or this:

```
Range(Cells(aa + 4, 1), Cells(bb + 4, 3)).Select
```

Also there is an article I've written on my blog about the different methods of referencing ranges in excel using VBA which covers this topic. [Referencing Ranges in Excel Using VBA](http://software-solutions-online.com/2014/02/21/retrieving-a-range-of-cells/)

Answer (score 0):

This little sub:

```
Sub dural()
    aa = 7
    bb = 11
    Range("A" & aa + 4 & ":C5" & bb + 4).Select
    MsgBox Selection.Address
End Sub
```

will produce:

**$A$11:$C$515**