# Linest Polynomial Regression in Excel's VBA

Tags: vba, excel, regression, excel-2013

I am having issues finding information on using Linest in Excel's VBA in a subroutine. I need to return the polynomial coefficients (third or fourth order) for a column of x values (Column A beginning in Row 17) and a column of y values (Column G beginning in Row 17).

The code I am currently using is shown below, and it works.

```
Dim X
X = Application.Evaluate("=linest(g17:g61,A17:A61^{1,2,3})")
Cells(3, 8) = X(1)
Cells(4, 8) = X(2)
Cells(5, 8) = X(3)
Cells(6, 8) = X(4)
```

Essentially, I need to be able to make this subroutine work on any length of data. Data will always begin to be entered in row 17. To do this, I have been trying to use code similar to that shown below.

```
Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row, 1)), Range(Cells(i, 2), Cells(Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row, 2))
```

However, when I use similar ranges to those above instead of `G17:G61` I get type mismatch errors. I don't understand why a range of cells is different from a range of cells in the format `G17:G61`. I've also tried using the simple `Range(Cells(17,1),Cells(61,1))` instead of `A17:A61`.

I have also tried using `"G" & 17:"G" & 61` instead of `G:17:G61` as I have seen some do while browsing, but that doesn't seem to fix my issues either.

Is there another function that might be better?

Please help!

Comment: Your title suggests this is an issue with doing regression in Excel. It's really an issue with programming ranges in Excel VBA. There is a lot of good content on that already in this site. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22202948/using-range-function-excel-with-variables) has a couple of simple examples.

Comment: I've had difficulty finding enough information on the Linest function in the capacity that I'm trying to use it (ie. VBA for higher polynomials), so I've been struggling to understand exactly what I should be inputting. Can you expand further?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first comment on your question puts you on the right track, `Application.Evaluate` takes a string (you have to build the reference to the range in that string). The second method using `Range` and `Cells` creates an object reference to the `Range`, if you want to use object references then instead of evaluating a string you would pass the references to `Application.WorksheetFunction.LinEst`.

Here's an example using the cell references in your original question.

```
Public Sub TestLinest()

Dim x
Dim i as long
Dim evalString As String
Dim sheetDisplayName As String
Dim polyOrder as string

' this is whatever the name of your sheet containing data:
sheetDisplayName = "Sheet1"
' this gets the index of the last cell in the data range
i = Range(sheetDisplayName & "!A17").End(xlDown).Row
' Obviously change this depending on how many polynomial terms you need
polyOrder = "{1,2,3}"

evalString = "=linest(" & sheetDisplayName & "!E6:E" & i & ", " & sheetDisplayName & "!D6:D" & i & "^" & polyOrder & ")"
x = Application.Evaluate(evalString)

Cells(3, 8) = x(1)
Cells(4, 8) = x(2)
Cells(5, 8) = x(3)
Cells(6, 8) = x(4) 

End Sub
```

You can see there are a couple of magic variables to fill in, in terms of ranges, sheet names and polynomial order. Perhaps this routine could be expanded to pass those as arguments to a function and return an array of coefficients?

---

At this point it might be worth mentioning that you could achieve all this without using VBA, which would mean that the spreadsheet logic remains more visible to you and/or your users. Here are some example functions to enable you to do all this on a sheet, here's the gist of it:

Get the total number of filled in cells (lets say this is in A1)

```
=COUNT(A17:A10000)
```

Enter this as an array formula:

```
=LINEST(INDIRECT("G17:G"&(A1+16)), INDIRECT("A17:A"&(A1+16))^{1,2,3})
```

The 16 and {1,2,3} in this formula can obviously be changed to suit your situation.

Comment: Try stepping through the code and use the locals windows to see what the variables contain. In this case x is a 2d array so I think you'll need something more like `x(1,1)`. Also I hadn't realised originally that you were  regressing against x, x^2, x^3. To do so you'll need to either add the cells on the spreadsheet or calculate the array yourself to pass to the LinEst function.

Comment: After further investigation, this is just returning the coefficients of the linear trend to the data. How can I modify this to return the cubic or quartic coefficients?